# railway.js node website on azure returns error and doesn't log

Tags: node.js, azure, railway.js

I'm getting an iisnode error 500 when trying to run a railway.js node application on azure.  Unfortunately there is nothing in the log files in LogFiles/nodejs nor in wwwroot/server.js.logs

Here is the response

```
iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The node.exe process has not written any information to the stdout or stderr.
```

The app works fine locally, and I can also deploy a vanilla hello world node app (not a railway.js app) to Azure.  How can I get more information about the error, is there anyway I can see the console output?

Comment: I've had this exact same issue. Restarting the website clears the error, but it comes back after periods of inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Restart does fix this.  It looks like it may have to do with the mechanism you use for session caching, as the default is incompatible with running under multiple instances.

To turn on logging, make sure that you have loggingEnabled: true in the iisnode.yml file, then you should be able to download logs